# Runtime error getting thrown with certain parameters on older 1.1 methods

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

This v1.1 URL is creating a runtime error:

> http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/comments&min=1323731212

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `?`, which .NET is interpreting as an attack and blocking.

http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/comments?min=1323731212  works.

Comment: *Slaps forehead for the second time today...*